# Replace last instance of a character in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a csv file with the data like this

```
Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks,7469,3.00
```

Unfortunately this is not correct as the first section should be all one field like this

```
"Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks","7469","3.00"
```

As this is just a once off import I would be just happy to transform it to

```
Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks|7469|3.00
```

with the last and second last comma's converted to pipes. Is there an easy way to do this with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert comma to pipe last 2 items, you could do like this

```
>>> re.sub(",(\d+),([\d.]+)$","|\\1|\\2","Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks,7469,3.00")
'Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks|7469|3.00'
```

Comment: Wait until a record turns up that has a decimal point in first number (or no decimal point in the second number)

Comment: @clee That would break my regex too - but that's against the question specs ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
s/(\S),(\S)/\1|\2/g
```

(Replaces all commas which have are surrounded on both sides by non-space characters with pipes.)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to pipes this way.  Just feed your text through this command:

```
sed 's/,\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)$/|\1|\2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test.csv 
Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks,7469,3.00
a,100,2000
a,b and c, 100,300

$ cat test.csv | perl -npe 's/^(.*),(.*),(.*)$/$1|$2|$3/'
Zoos, Sanctuaries & Animal Parks|7469|3.00
a|100|2000
a,b and c| 100|300
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert last commas into pipes:

Replace `^(.*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?)$` with `$1|$2|$3`

Or even better - to convert them in to the correct format:

Replace `^(.*?),([^,]*?),([^,]*?)$` with `"$1","$2","$3"`